# How to move image in VrPanoramaView dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, panoramas

I am using following image in `VrPanoramaView`

[image]

When i load it in the view, it looks like this.

[image]

But i want it to move the image to left side dynamically before opening the image, like this.

[image]

I can move the image with finger, but i want it to set its angle at the loading time.

This is my code.

```
VrPanoramaView.Options options = new VrPanoramaView.Options();
InputStream inputStream = null;
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

inputStream = assetManager.open("test_2"+ ".jpg");
options.inputType = VrPanoramaView.Options.TYPE_MONO;

mVrPanoramaView.loadImageFromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream), options);

mVrPanoramaView.setStereoModeButtonEnabled(false);
mVrPanoramaView.setInfoButtonEnabled(false);
mVrPanoramaView.setPureTouchTracking(true);
mVrPanoramaView.setFullscreenButtonEnabled(true);
```

I tried `mVrPanoramaView.setPivotX(100);`, but it does not make any impact. I need to know how to translate image in panorama view with using any hand gesture.

I am using `GoogleVrSDK`

```
implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.160.0'
implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.170.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

I think, you should switch to [Video360](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/video360):

There are more signs this component is not under development any more.

1. [Set initial angle of VrPanoramaView](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/586)

> There are no plans to add more functionality to the VrView widgets.
>   But you more complex controls for a 360 media player, consider using
>   the Video360 sample as a starting point. See #510 for more info.

2. [VR View for Android](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/android/vrview)

> Warning: These components were removed in v1.190 of the GVR SDK for
>   Android. The Video360 sample should be used as a basis for creating
>   360 photo and video viewers. If you still want to use these widgets,
>   you will need to use SDK v1.180 or earlier.